Styling specific ng-prime components
I'm having a hard time trying to apply styles to 'ng-prime' elements
more specifically for the element 'p-fileUpload' from the https://primeng.org/fileupload
this is the html and scsss I'm using:
        <div class="actions actions-box actions-10" [ngClass]="action10Class">
            <div id='ldprogram' class="flex justify-content-between align-items-center pt-2 pl-4">
                <div class="flex justify-content-between align-items-center gap-2">
                    <p class="text-primary font-bold my-auto">L&D Program Administration</p>
                </div>
                <div class="flex justify-content-end gap-2">
                    <p-button icon="pi pi-times" styleClass="p-button-rounded p-button-text" (onClick)="closeStepInfo()"></p-button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <div class="diagram-table-view">
                    <p-tabView>
                        <p-tabPanel header="Data Input">
                            <ng-template pTemplate="content">
                                <p-fileUpload 
                                    styleClass="common-file-upload new-data-output" 
                                    mode="basic" 
                                    name="demo[]" 
                                    chooseIcon="pi-plus-circle" 
                                    [auto]="true" 
                                    chooseLabel="New Data Output" />
        
                                <div id="separator">
                                    <p>Or</p>
                                </div>
        
                                <p-fileUpload
                                    styleClass="common-file-upload import-step" 
                                    mode="basic" 
                                    name="demo[]" 
                                    chooseIcon="pi-file-import" 
                                    [auto]="true" 
                                    chooseLabel="Import from existing step" />
                            </ng-template>
                        </p-tabPanel>
                        <p-tabPanel header="Data Output">
                            <ng-template pTemplate="content">
                                <p-fileUpload 
                                    styleClass="common-file-upload new-data-input" 
                                    mode="basic" 
                                    name="demo[]" 
                                    chooseIcon="pi-plus-circle" 
                                    [auto]="true" 
                                    chooseLabel="New Data Input" />
                            </ng-template>
                        </p-tabPanel>
                        <p-tabPanel header="Business Rules">
                            <ng-template pTemplate="content">
                                <div class="flex flex-column flex-wrap gap-3 px-3">
                                    <div class="flex flex-column gap-2">
                                        <label for="usecase-name">Rule Name</label>
                                        <input
                                            pInputText
                                            id="usecase-name"
                                            aria-describedby="name-help"
                                        />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="flex flex-column gap-2">
                                        <label for="usecase-description">Description</label>
                                        <textarea
                                            rows="5"
                                            cols="30"
                                            pInputTextarea
                                            id="usecase-description"
                                            aria-describedby="description-help"></textarea>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </ng-template>
                        </p-tabPanel>
                    </p-tabView>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

This is the last thing I've tried, of course I tried direct methods and nothing seems to work
.content .diagram-table-view p-tabView p-tabPanel .common-file-upload.ui-fileupload {
    width: 100% !important;
    background-color: transparent !important;
    color: var(--primary-color) !important;
    border: 1px solid lightgrey !important;
    border-radius: 4px !important;
}

STyles being applied to the element

The style is probably not applied due to view encapsulation
